# How to edit a line of a file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, file

How can i edit a specific line of a text file in python ?

I have tried .replace() but i don't want to change the data in the python string.
Only thing i want is making changes to the text file (and not even appending to the last line of it)

I have this text file for example :

```
Hello
World!
```

and i want it to become like this :

```
Hi
World!
```

Should I use a code like this?:

```
text_file = open(myfile, "r")
text_file[0]="Hi"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not gonna work In `python3` , since `readlines` returns an iterator, not a list. If the file is not too big, you can load all in memmory and then write it:

```
with open(myfile, "r") as f:
    data = list(f.readlines())

# modify first line
data[0] = "Hi!"

with open(myfile, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(data)
```